# Linux виртуальноая машины

Tags: linux, виртуальная-машина, ping

У меня есть компьютер 'А' с виртуальной машиной (qemu) и компьютер 'Б'. Я хочу запинговать из виртуальной машины -> компьютер 'Б', но не знаю какие настройки для этого нужно провести. Оба компьютера и виртуалка на linux debian.

У меня получилось запинговать компьютер А (без виртуалки) -> компьютер 'Б', но с виртуалкой уже 'Destination host is unreachable'. Как можно это исправить?

Comment: 1. нужно добавить сетевой адаптер в конфигурацию виртуальной машины. 2. нужно настроить сеть в операционной системе, запущенной в качестве виртуальной машины.

Comment: А ещё виртуальный сетевой адаптер должен подключать виртуальную машину напрямую в сеть (bridged), чтобы виртуалка получала/имела адрес в той же подсети, что и базовая ОС. И пингать надо по адресу виртуальной машины. Как именно это делается - зависит от конкретного VMM.